# How to avoid my coding to do not save data on active sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in a workbook having two sheets named "Data" and "Daily". I just want my code save new inputs in daily sheet,but instead of doing this it is saving in the active sheet.I will be grateful if somebody can solve this issue.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Saving Button
    Dim sonsat As Long

    sonsat = Sheets("Daily").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Call Main 'Progress Bar

    Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1
    Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox2
    Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox3
    Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox4
    Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox5

    MsgBox "Registration is successful"
    ListBox1.List = Sheets("Daily").Range("A2:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value 'For refresh listbox
    TextBox14.Value = ListBox1.ListCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add reference to Daily sheet in this way:

```
With Sheets("Daily")
   .Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1 'dot at the beginning is very important...
   .Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox2
   .Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox3
   .Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox4
   .Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox5
end with
```